Proof of $\int_{\Omega_2}f(y)\mu{\circ}T^{-1}(dy)=\int_{\Omega_1}f(T(x))\mu(dx)$
Theorem. Suppose $(\Omega_1,\mathcal A,\mu)$ is a measure space and $(\Omega_2,\mathcal A_2)$ is a measurable space. If $T:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$ and $f:\Omega_2\rightarrow\bar{\mathbb {R}}$ are measurable then,
$$\int_{\Omega_2}f(y)\mu{\circ}T^{-1}(dy)=\int_{\Omega_1}f(T(x))\mu(dx)\tag{$*$}$$
whenever the integral on either side makes sense.

Attempted proof. The above result for a general $f$. We first look at the case when $f$ as a simple non-negative function. Then, we may write $f$ as
$$f(y)=\mathbb I_A(y)\qquad\forall y\in\Omega_2$$
for some $A\subset\Omega_2$. Since $T:\Omega_1\rightarrow\Omega_2$, it folows that
$$f(T(x))=\mathbb I_A(T(x))=\mathbb I_{T^{-1}A}(x)\qquad\forall x\in\Omega_1.$$
So, $$\int_{\Omega_1}f(T(x))\mu(dx)=\int_{\Omega_1}\mathbb I_{T^{-1}A}(x)\mu(dx)$$
and
$$\int_{\Omega_2}f(y)\mu{\circ}T^{-1}(dy)=\int_{\Omega_2}\mathbb I_A(y)\mu{\circ}T^{-1}(dy).$$
[Update thanks to @geetha290krm @IzaakvanDongen] The two integrals are equal. So, the result is true for any non-negative simple function. We want to show that it holds for any $f$. There exist simple functions $f_n$ such that $0\le f_n\uparrow f$.

Then, is it necessarily true that $0\le f_n\circ T\uparrow f\circ T$?

Assuming it is, we get by Monotone Convergence theorem, LHS and RHS of $(*)$ are equal.

The two integrals you got are equal by definition of $\mu \circ T^{-1}$.

In general, do you know how to evaluate the integral of an indicator function? (If not, you may benefit from having another look at the early parts of the definition of the integral)

@IzaakvanDongen Oh you're right how silly of me. It is simiply $\sum_\Omega \mu(T^{-1}A)$ and hence the equality

(... this is the so called transport formula in mass theory / probability theory  - there is no "change of variables" at this level of completely disorganized matter regarding smoothness.)
